# Django Template render problems

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm a novice in learning django and I've come across rendering data in django templates using `{{ }}`.

I've made a SQLite table and I'm trying to make it render its values.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from app1.models import Merch


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Index page!")


def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World!")


def store(request):
    context = {"stuff": Merch}

    return render(request, 'app1/store.html', context)
```

app1/templates/app1/store.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>
    <h1>TEMPLATE</h1>
    <p>{{ stuff }}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

the HTML part renders fine (big TEMPLATE text visible) but the django template for "stuff" is not.

any idea how to get this working?

Comment: `stuff` is a reference to a model class, not a queryset of objects for example. Exactly *what * do you want to do?

Comment: I wish to display the queryset. from the tutorial I'm following it should be displaying "<QuerySet ...>" but I get noting

Comment: So ... you need to provide a queryset; e.g. `Merch.objects.all`.  I'm sure that the tutorial does NOT say to provide a model class in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only pass a reference to the model class, not a queryset, you can work with:

```
def store(request):
    context = {'stuff': Merch.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'app1/store.html', context)
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't realize that I needed to provide a model class.